# can set string data to state with axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, state

I want to save the string received from API in the state, but it can't.
First I wrote a Python code as follows that returns the first 3 letters of the username (each username is entered so that the first three letters specify its type).
this is Django(python) code:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class usertype(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        try:
            user=request.user
        except:
            raise ValueError('error')
            return Response({
               'username':user.username[:3],
            })
```

then i write this code in react for separate dashboards:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import DashboardS from './Students/DashboardS';
import DashboardT from './Teachers/DashboardT';
import axios from 'axios';

const api=axios.create({
     baseURL:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/usertype/'
})

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);  
      this.state={
        usertype:'',
        showS:false,
        showT:false,
       } 
      this.showDash=this.showDash.bind(this);    
      this.getusertype=this.getusertype.bind(this);    
    
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getusertype();
        this.showDash();
    }


    getusertype(){
        api.get('/').then(res=>{
            this.setState({
               usertype:res.data.username,
            });
            console.log(res.data.username); // out is std for stduent user
        });        
    }
    showDash(){
        switch(this.state.usertype){
            case "std":
               this.setState({
                   showS:true,showT:false,
               })
             break;
            case "tcr":
                this.setState({
                    showS:false,showT:true,
                })
               break;          
           }
    }
    render() {
         return (
             <div>

                {this.state.showS && <DashboardS/>}
                {this.state.showT && <DashboardT/>}
            
            </div>
         )
      }
   }
```

how can i solve this problem.
help me.

Comment: I think you got a spelling error on line 3 in your python script. It should probably be spelled "Response".

Comment: Its may not help you but why `baseUrl` is `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/usertype/"`?
baseUrl in this case must be `"http://127.0.0.1:8000"` and you must call `"/accounts/userType`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call is an async operation meaning other code will continue to execute until the response is received. You `showDash` function is called before the usertype is set in state. Update your code to call `showDash` like this

```
getusertype(){
        api.get('/').then(res=>{
            this.setState({
               usertype:res.data.username,
            },()=>{
                this.showDash();
            });
            console.log(res.data.username); // out is std for stduent user
        });        
    }
```

Comment: @mr.pro will you have more logic in the showDash function later? because if not alishi973's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

First you have two state that name `showS:false,showT:false` but in render block, used `showD` that this state is not exist in your initial states.

Second, Instead of using `showDash()` for conditional rendering, use ternary operator:

```
...
render() {
         return (
             <div>
                {this.state.usertype === "std" ? <DashboardS/> : <DashboardT/>}
            </div>
         )
      }
   }
...
```

Comment: thats true but not the answer of my poblem!